# Postgresql pg_hba.conf changes are ignored or not loaded

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, ubuntu, pg-hba.conf

Using Postgresql 9.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

I've been changing the /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf config file madly trying to make a change that will allow me to log in with any user remotely.

My current configuration looks like so:

```
host all postgres <remote-ip>/32 trust
asdf asdf asdf
1 1
1-1-1-1-
```

This is, of course, a completely bogus config file.  However, when I run

```
sudo service postgresql restart
sudo service postgresql reload
```

Both commands succeed with status `[ OK ]` - there are no parse errors.  I have also disabled all entries that start with `local` and yet I am still able to login as the postgres user.

Any attempts to log into the server remotely from the  host
using:

```
psql -c 'SELECT version()' -h pg -U postgres
```

Result in:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I am clearly not trying to use password authentication.

### EDIT:

Running `SHOW hba_file;` as the postgres user yeilds

```
                hba_file
--------------------------------------
 /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)
```

### Edit 2:

Checking the logs shows that the parse errors were happening.  I have cleaned out the bogus lines, leaving

```
host all postgres <remote-ip>/32 trust
```

I am still getting a password prompt for some reason.  There is nothing in the log after a failed login.

Comment: can you check logs ? after you run the command 'reload'

Comment: @SahapAsci Question modified to reflect my findings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.  This was a long shot, but it may help someone who has exhausted the normal avenues or is not used to postgres.

The server I was working on had another instance running through puppet, and so the config I was modifying was not for the instance I was connecting to.

run `find / -name 'postgresql.conf'` to see if there are any other locations where you might have a postgres instance.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, the message is there plain to see:

> psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "**posgres**"

Typo!

Comment: A typo while I was re-gathering output to paste here. Exact same problem when I correct this typo.  Note that I can get the password-authentication error for any arbitrary user.